# Can somebody recommend a good word to describe somebody with great responsibility

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm looking for  word that would describe a ruler or any leader with great responsibilities which has shown themselves to be very caring and ready to go the extra mile. could the word magnanimous be used in this context? eg. "for those of us with magnanimous responsibilities...."

Comment: With great responsibility comes... Spider-Man?

Comment: Would you like a word to describe the responsible person, or the responsibilities themselves? Your question asks for the first, but your example is of the second.

Comment: The responsibilities they are burdened with are not likely to be magnanimous, while someone who shoulders them well may or may not be.

Comment: If you want a word to describe a responsible person, such a leader can be termed as a Role model.

Answer (score 2):

According to OED, a ***[magnanimous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/magnanimous)*** leader is one who is:

> Very generous or forgiving, especially toward a rival or someone less
>   powerful than oneself.

Since the root idea of magnanimous is from the Latin

> *magnus* = *big* + *animus* = *soul*

It can still serve to express **any greatness** in a man's life. A list of common [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/magnanimous?s=t) supports this usage:

> altruistic, charitable, considerate, forgiving, selfless, unselfish,
>   unstinting, all heart, beneficent, benevolent, big, bighearted,
>   bountiful, free, generous, great, greathearted, handsome, has heart in
>   right place, high-minded, kindly, knightly, liberal, lofty, loose,
>   munificent, noble, openhanded, Santa Claus, soft, soft-touch,
>   ungrudging

*Magnanimous* would refer to the leader, not the responsibilities, but you might refer to the responsibilities as

***[extraordinary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/extraordinary)***,

which communicates the idea of going the extra mile in reference to the responsibilities the leader took upon himself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked: not really, no.

Using the term "magnanimous responsibilities" means that the responsibilities are magnanimous, which doesn't make a ton of sense.

You might describe the individual as magnanimous, but you wouldn't say the person had "magnanimous responsibilities".

I'd recommend checking out a thesaurus and looking up synonyms for "responsible" as a start.

You might also consider looking for a longer phrase. A sentence like "despite being burdened by responsibility, he was always a magnanimous leader" might get the point across pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think of Churchill or Lincoln.  They took charge, assumed the duty and shouldered the responsibilty.  "Charged with" comes to mind, along with "pillar", "pioneer" and "philanthropist"...